# Passwords are not stored in any browser except Firefox

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-10

I have domain user accounts (Windows Active Directory) that they use the same (1-1) Windows 10 domain PC some years without problems about saving passwords to browsers. But if I use the same domain user accounts to login to a different pc then I can't save any password to any browser except Firefox!!! Only with the bult-in domain administrator account I am not having any problem when I logged in to any domain pc. There are not group policies (local or domain).